# CSS menu isn't working in IE 8 and less

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6, cross-browser

Piece of crap IE, just literally hate it.
Ok, this is what I did, [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/adijey).
How do I make menu-bar look prettier or similar, like in FF&Chrome, in older versions of IE?
Also I dont get it, when nesting elements like `#nav ul li` they are not applied in IE 8 and less, why?

Answer (score 3):

A little piece of solution, maybe it will help you achieve what you're looking for :

For enabling certain HTML5 functions disabled in older IEs :

- [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/)
- [Shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/)

Both of them can help you achieve your result. Hope it will help you, if not, feel free to discard my answer.

Comment: thnx! yes I heard about modernizr but do you any good resources that explains how to use them?

Comment: as the basic level, just include the Modernizr javascript file at the top of your code, and your HTML5 elements should start working in IE. There's a lot more to it, but that's enough to answer your question. The alternative, of course, is not to use HTML5 elements if you want to support old browsers.

Answer (score 2):

You should add html5 shim, because older IE doesn't understand HTML5 tags. You can also move id to ul instead of header element

Comment: thnx for solving `ul` issue and what is html5 shim?

Comment: Use Modernizr instead of html5Shim -- Modernizr includes html5Shim as part of the package.